# In general, does Texas A&M or University of Florida have a better reputation in mathematics?

Tags: phd, mathematics

I have been accepted to both of these schools' PhD programs in Mathematics. I know they have different mathematical strengths as departments; however, I'm wondering if being an alumni of one of those schools vs. the other would likely affect my job placement after I graduate, assuming I seek an academic position. In other words, does anyone know which of these schools has more success in securing their alumni better positions at better universities? I've looked for this information on both of the universities' websites but not had much luck.

Comment: Voting to close; the minimum-distance question that would be welcome here is "Is there a published statistic of universities in the USA ranking them based on which percentage of their phd students in mathematics manage to find a tenured job?"

Comment: Consistent with what @PeteL.Clark writes below, the assumption that some ranking/prestige of a university is the main employability determiner for PhD's is not accurate, even beyond the dubiousness of these rankings. The criteria for ranking are not tightly connected to employability of alumni. The work you do in your thesis, how you present yourself in job applications, the reputation of your advisor, and what they say about you in their letter for your job app will have much more impact than various mostly-commodified "rankings".

Comment: More than the global ranking, consider that each of these departments will have strengths in different areas. What will matter more to you is whether one or the other is strong in the area you care about. For example, Texas A&M (disclaimer: this is my department) is strong in operator theory and numerical analysis (and a bunch of other areas); but if you're into foundations of mathematics or probability, it may not be your choice.

Answer (score 6):

US News and World report ranks math departments according to their reputation in the profession: [see here](http://grad-schools.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-graduate-schools/top-science-schools/mathematics-rankings).  These ratings should be used broadly: i.e., just because a school is higher doesn't mean it actually has a meaningfully higher reputation.  You will do better to use these rankings to divide schools into larger groups of the same approximate quality.

In this case, the two departments you ask about are currently ranked #41 and #56.  For me this means both departments are (i) quite good, though measurably worse than a school in the top 25 like Rutgers or UCSD and (ii) so close in overall reputation that the question "which is better, globally?" is not going to have a meaningful answer.  (For good measure, my own department falls in between these two departments in the rankings, and indeed I view both departments as being rather close peers.)  For these two schools, any global differences in prestige would be drowned out by many other things, e.g. the prestige of your thesis advisor and/or the research group within the school, connections between a particular department and particular employer...and of course how successful you are in one department versus the other and the quality of your thesis work.

In short: in this case, pick whatever department is better for you, and don't worry about prestige.